# Customized comparison function in common lisp

Tags: list, comparison, common-lisp

I need to compare two lists and equalp doing just fine when I have the nested lists in order, but I need a custom function that returns T when I have the order of nested lists mixed. Something like;

```lisp
    (setq temp1 '(((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR FS) (MODAL STAR)
      (((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (MODAL STAR) (DIR BS)  ((FEATS NIL) (BCAT NP)))))

    (setq temp2 '((DIR FS) ((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (MODAL STAR)
      (((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR BS) (MODAL STAR) ((BCAT NP) (FEATS NIL)))))

    (equalp-customized temp1 temp2) ; gotta make this return T
```

I had tried to find the source code of equalp, it was not a good idea I guess, I then could have altered it to support my needs. Now I have no clue where to start. Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that doing this naively, by recursively comparing all elements, is likely too slow, as it is quadratic on every level.

Instead, I'd propose to bring these trees into a canonical form first, and then use `equalp`.  A canonical form means that the order is made consistent across all trees.

Comment: So recursively ordering then the trees will be effectively `equal` if they both contain the same elements. Nice

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your input trees are composed only of atomic 2-element lists at the lowest level. If so, you can simply flatten the trees into plists and then check for equal sets. (However, if the lowest level lists can contain an arbitrary number of atoms, then you would need to extract those lists by walking the input trees first.)

The Alexandria library contains the function `flatten`, but it would remove the `nil` entries in the inputs. Here is an alternate function to do the same thing, but respecting NILs. The result is a plist of the input 2-element lists.

```
(defun level-out (tree)
  "Flattens a tree respecting NILs."
  (loop for item in tree
        when (consp item)
          if (atom (car item))
            append item
          else append (level-out item)))
```

So now, for example:

(setq flat1 (level-out temp1)) -> (BCAT S FEATS NIL DIR FS MODAL STAR BCAT S FEATS NIL MODAL STAR DIR BS FEATS NIL BCAT NP)

The following function then collects the pairs:

```
(defun pair-up (plist)
  (loop for (1st 2nd) on plist by #'cddr
      collect (list 1st 2nd)))
```

giving:

(setq pairs1 (pair-up flat1)) -> ((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL) (DIR FS) (MODAL STAR) (BCAT S) (FEATS NIL) (MODAL STAR) (DIR BS) (FEATS NIL) (BCAT NP))

The pairs are now in a form for testing set equality using Alexandria:

```
(defun nested-pairs-equal-p (tree1 tree2)
  (alexandria:set-equal (pair-up (level-out tree1))
                        (pair-up (level-out tree2))
                        :test #’equal))

(nested-pairs-equal-p temp1 temp2) -> T
```

**Extracting Nested Lists**

Actually, it may be more straightforward to extract the nested lists directly with:

```
(defun level-out-nested-lists (tree)
  (loop for item in tree
      if (and (consp item) (atom (car item)))
      collect item
      else append (level-out-nested-lists item)))
```

before checking for alexandria:set-equal.

**Extracting Nested Lists Indexed by Level**

The basic idea again is to walk the two input lists extracting the lowest level items, but associating each extracted item with its level in the tree. The following function purports to create an alist of items where the car is the level and the cdr is the list of items appearing at that level:

```
(defun associate-tree-items-by-level (tree)
  "Returns an alist of items in tree indexed by level."
  (let (alist)
    (labels ((associate-tree-items-by-level-1 (tree level)
               (loop for item in tree
                 when (consp item)
                  if (atom (car item))
                   do (let ((pair (assoc level alist)))
                        (if pair
                          (rplacd pair (push item (cdr pair)))
                          (push (cons level (list item)) alist)))
                   else do (associate-tree-items-by-level-1 item (1+ level)))))
      (associate-tree-items-by-level-1 tree 1)
      (sort alist #'< :key #'first))))
```

So then:

```
(associate-tree-items-by-level
  '(((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR BS) (MODAL STAR) (((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (MODAL STAR) (DIR FS) ((FEATS NIL) (BCAT NP)))))
->  ((1 (MODAL STAR) (DIR BS))
 (2 (DIR FS) (MODAL STAR) (FEATS NIL) (BCAT S))
 (3 (BCAT NP) (FEATS NIL) (FEATS NIL) (BCAT S)))
```

All of the items are now grouped into bags (not sets because of possible repetitions) and indexed by level. The next function should test for equal bags of items:

```
(defun bag-equal-p (bag-list1 bag-list2)
  (and (= (length bag-list1) (length bag-list2))
       (loop with remainder = (copy-list bag-list2)
         for item1 in bag-list1
         do (alexandria:deletef remainder item1 :test #'equal :count 1)
         finally (return (not remainder)))))
```

To check equality of the inputs, you can then do something like:

```
(every #'bag-equal-p 
  (associate-tree-items-by-level input1)
  (associate-tree-items-by-level input2))
```

(ps: I haven’t really tested the above code, so you may need to make some adjustments. It’s only offered as prototyping.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but how about this example;

    (((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR *BS*) (MODAL STAR)
          (((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (MODAL STAR) (DIR *FS*)  ((FEATS NIL) (BCAT NP)))))

Versus

    ((DIR _FS_) ((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (MODAL STAR)
      (((BCAT S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR _BS_) (MODAL STAR) ((BCAT NP) (FEATS NIL))))

these two (DIR _BS_) and (DIR _FS_)s are in different levels deep. This should not return true, but if we level out the whole thing, it would be a false positive right?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are looking for now. You want the same items at different levels in the tree to count as different items for the purpose of comparison? See the edit above for this alternative.